# find the number of ways to write a word of length k over an n-letter alphabet so that the word uses every letter at least once?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, find the number of ways to write a
word of length k over an n-letter alphabet so that the word uses every letter at least once?

how should I approach this?

Comment: Why don't you first search this site for similar problems ?

Comment: @true blue anil I couldnt find anything similar, perhaps you could give me a link?

Comment: This is inclusion-exclusion with Stirling numbers which was presented e.g. at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109526/).

Comment: @ Marko Riedel would you please give me some hints? I did not understand the link at all. I can not relate the method of inclusion and exclusion to the asking of this question. something is missing without which I just can't seem to understand what the question is asking.